# Why do I get an undefined value from the defineProperty method?

Tags: javascript, arrow-functions, es6-proxy

```
var funcSetter = {

    defineProperty: function(target, prop, descriptor) {
        if (prop) {
            let temp = descriptor.value;
            descriptor.value = temp => {
                if (temp.startsWith('_')) {
                    temp = "Default Value Attached , no Underscores allowed";
                    return temp;
                } else return temp;
            };
        }
        return true;
    }
};

let proxy_3 = new Proxy(obj_3, funcSetter);

Object.defineProperty(proxy_3, 'no', {
    value: '_Bharath',
    writable: true,
    enumerable: true,
    configurable: true
});
```

The issue I am facing here is that when I call the trap `defineProperty`, the arrow function defined under `descriptor.value` does not get called, hits the return true at the bottom and sets the value of the property as `undefined`

I am quite sure I haven't used the arrow function correctly. Could anyone guide me in the right direction?

Thank you for all the tips. Much appreciated!

Comment: please add some use cases.

Comment: This is something , I was experimenting with while learning proxies and Reflect in JS. No use case per se.

Comment: *The defineProperty method must return a Boolean indicating whether or not the property has been successfully defined* - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy/handler/defineProperty#Return_value

Comment: Yes I am aware , but when I try to access the property value of 'no', I get undefined.

Comment: sorry, misread your code :p

Comment: Stepped through the code , to see that the arrow function never gets called . Hence would like to know why this is the case

Comment: .. LOL. Okay. the arrow function gets applied as the value actually to descriptor.value

Comment: I think one problem is your `let temp` and your `temp` argument are confusing you

Comment: No ,it's not , I am using temp within the scope of the defineProperty function and would like to set this value based on the condition in the arrow function.  Can you please elaborate on that?

Comment: well the outer `temp` is lost, and not available inside the arrow function - but that's not the reason your code doesn't work as expected

Comment: Oh .. Thank you .. I really didn't notice that.

Comment: What else can it be ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems:

1. You're just *assigning* the arrow function to `descriptor.value`. Not calling it.
2. You're not actually *setting* the property anywhere.

I think this should solve the problem

```js
var funcSetter = {

  defineProperty: function(target, prop, descriptor) {
    if (prop) {
      let temp = descriptor.value;
      // Use an IIFE
      descriptor.value = (temp => {
        if (temp.startsWith('_')) {
          return "Default Value Attached , no Underscores allowed";
        } else {
          return temp;
        };
      })(temp);
    }
    // Use Reflect.defineProperty to actually set the property
    return Reflect.defineProperty(target, prop, descriptor);
  }
};

let obj_3 = {};
let proxy_3 = new Proxy(obj_3, funcSetter);

Object.defineProperty(proxy_3, 'no', {
  value: '_Bharath',
  writable: true,
  enumerable: true,
  configurable: true
});

console.log(obj_3);
```

Also, a **MUCH** simpler way to do this

```js
var funcSetter = {

  defineProperty: function(target, prop, descriptor) {
    if (prop) {
      if (descriptor.value.startsWith('_')) {
        descriptor.value = "Default Value Attached , no Underscores allowed";
      }
    }
    // Use Reflect.defineProperty to actually set the property
    return Reflect.defineProperty(target, prop, descriptor);
  }
}
let obj_3 = {};
let proxy_3 = new Proxy(obj_3, funcSetter);

Object.defineProperty(proxy_3, 'no', {
  value: '_Bharath',
  writable: true,
  enumerable: true,
  configurable: true
});

console.log(obj_3);
```

Comment: the iife is far over engineered.

Comment: I agree. Trying to change the OP's code with least modifications. A normal `if..else` should actually suffice.

Comment: I tried a simpler straightforward approach to this problem and solved it , but it bugged me as to why the arrow function approach did not work.

Comment: @MaazSyedAdeeb Thank you for your solution ,  I am new to IIFE's  Are there any potential advantages to this approach ?

Comment: In your case, I don't think there are any advantages. An IIFE is nothing but a function that is executed immediately after its definition.